# How to set rails request timeout longer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timeout, puma

My app is built on rails and the web server is puma.

I need to load data from database and it takes more than 60 seconds to load all of them. Every time I send a get request to the server, I have to wait more than 60 seconds.

The timeout of request get is 60 seconds, so I always get 504 gateway timeout. I can't find the place to change the request timeout in puma configuration.
How can I set the request timeout longer than 60 seconds?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're request is taking more than 30 seconds, that's unacceptable for a web server and should be fixed.  Boosting time-outs is putting a bandaid on a turd.  You need to post what your code is trying to do in DB that's taking so  long to get better help on this question.  I have not downvoted your question.  But please give us something to help you with.

Comment: Sure, but what if I want to profile my long-running action, but profiling make it last longer than 30s? Not all timeout increases are a bandaid, but this would be actually helpful to investigate your app's performance issues.

Answer (score 5):

****UPDATE**: Apparently worker_timeout is NOT the answer, as it relates to the whole process hanging, not just an individual request. So it seems to be something Puma doesn't support, and the developers are expecting you to implement it with whatever is fronting Puma, such as Nginx.**

*ORIGINAL: Rails itself doesn't time out, but use [worker_timeout](https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/2668597ec1dd9546d83db9f2ec5ad092add483e6/examples/config.rb#L179) in `config/puma.rb` if you're running Puma. Example:*

*worker_timeout (24*60*60) if ENV['RAILS_ENV']=='development'*

[Source](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/1024)

Comment: This is not a request timeout, it is to protect against a hung or dead process. Setting this value will not protect against slow requests.

Comment: Hey OP, I believe this is a correct answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77246217/299774 do you think it would be a good idea to link it in this, highest upvoted, one?

Answer (score 0):

The 504 error here is with the gateway in front of the rails server, for example it could be Cloudflare, or nginx etc.

So the settings would be there. You'd have to increase the timeout there, as well as in rails/puma.

Answer (score 0):

Puma by default [would not timeout requests based on time](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/160#issuecomment-9674468)

If you're seeing something like

```
Puma caught this error: R
equest ran for longer than 30000ms  (Rack::Timeout::RequestTimeoutErro
r
```

It means you have some kind of middleware that gives you that behavior, in the case above it's https://github.com/zombocom/rack-timeout

Search for `Rack::Timeout` in your codebase, that will look something like this:

```
  Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before Rack::Runtime,
    Rack::Timeout,
    service_timeout: Integer(30000)
```

and change the config to increase the timeout, or disable (not insert) the middleware altogether.

Answer (score -4):

Preferably, you should be optimizing your code and queries to respond in faster duration of time so that in production environment there is no bottleneck with large traffic coming on your application.

If you really want to increase the response time then you can use rack timeout to do this:

https://github.com/kch/rack-timeout

Comment: I'm sorry for my confusing description. I have tried rack-timeout, but the problem is when I wait for 60 seconds, I get a 504 gateway timeout. At the same time, the database query still works and it lasts about 90 seconds (longer than 60 seconds). So every time I query the database, I can not get the result from query within 60 seconds. Rack-timeout only limit the work time of the query.

Comment: I have tried the same on my local machine and it seems to work...are you using any web server like nginx or apache??

Comment: You should use rack-timeout at 60 seconds, then add a database timeout less than 60 seconds. If you're using postgres as your database then you could use a statement_timeout of 50 seconds, for instance.